# Construct superclass Provider from subclass's provider

Tags: java, guice

I have a superclass with its own nested class which is passed (/injected as provider) in the constructor.

Similarly i have a subclass with its own nested class which is injected (as a provider) in the constructor. Subclass.NestedClass extends Superclass.NestedClass.

```
public class SuperClass {
  @Inject SuperClass(Provider<SuperClass.Parameters> superParam) {
  }

  public class Parameters {
    int a;  
  }
}

public class Sub extends SuperClass {
  @Inject Sub(Provider<Sub.Parameters> subParam) {
     // Need to call super here with the appropriate superclass's provider
  }

  public class Parameters extends SuperClass.Parameters {
    int b;
  }
}
```

Is there a way i can convert the Provider of Sub.Parameters to SuperClass.Parameters's provider so that i can call super(with that provider) in the constructor of Sub.

Comment: Figured it out myself.  Superclass's constructor will now read @Inject SuperClass(Provider<? extends SuperClass.Parameters>. "? extends" solved my problem.

Comment: Please add it as an answer and mark it solved. It's perfectly legal to answer your own questions and it will help the others. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java generics helped me here.

Solution:

```
public class SuperClass {
  // Constructor
  @Inject SuperClass(Provider<? extends SuperClass.Parameters> superParam) {
  }

  public class Parameters {
    int a;  
  }
}

public class Sub extends SuperClass {
  @Inject Sub(Provider<Sub.Parameters> subParam) {
     super(subParam);
  }

  public class Parameters extends SuperClass.Parameters {
    int b;
  }
}
```

Observe the difference in the super class constructor's parameter "? extends".